# "Access Denied" editing HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE in Windows 8.1 running as Administrator

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I have Visual Studio 2013 set to "Run as Adminstrator" and `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>` in **app.manifest**. When I build my C# WPF project I get:

`Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\[edited]' is denied.`

This is the same source code previously building fine on Windows 7/VS 2012. I have since changed to a SSD with Windows 8.1 and now get the error above on Windows 8.1/VS 2013.

Are there some new security restrictions in 8.1 that prevent VS writing to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE even when running as Administrator?